# RTCPeerConnection Event not fire

Tags: javascript, angular, webrtc

I can't make an RTCPeerConnection working. After i create an RTCPeerConnection object, nothing happen. Events are not fired. This is the method that create the connection :

```
createPeerConnection() {
    console.log('new RtCPeerConnection with stun server.');
    this.myPeerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({stunServer}]
    });

    console.log('PeerConnection is ', this.myPeerConnection);

    this.myPeerConnection.onicecandidate = this.handleICECandidateEvent;
    this.myPeerConnection.ontrack = this.handleAddTrackEvent;
    this.myPeerConnection.removeTrack = this.handleRemoveStreamEvent;
    this.myPeerConnection.oniceconnectionstatechange = this.handleICEConnectionStateChangeEvent;
    // this.myPeerConnection.onicegatheringstatechange = this.handleICEGatheringStateChangeEvent;
    // this.myPeerConnection.onsignalingstatechange = this.handleSignalingStateChangeEvent;
    this.myPeerConnection.onnegotiationneeded = this.handleNegotiationNeededEvent;
  }
```

I have not error in console. Just nothing happened. 
This method is called when user click on another user to connect :

```
connect() {
    console.log('Creating RTCPeerConnetion...');
    this.createPeerConnection();
    console.log('RTCPeerConnection created');
    console.log('Creating new local stream ...');
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then((localStream) => {
      this.localVideo.nativeElement.srcObject = localStream;
      console.log('Local stream created', localStream);
    }).catch(this.handleGetUserMediaError);
  }
```

I used Firefox and Angular2 and i test this on localhost. Don't know if this can be the cause.  any idea?

Comment: Just creating the connection won't cause any events to be fired. That will only happen when the offer/answer is exchanged between the two peers. I'd recommend checking out: https://webrtc.org/start/

Answer (score 0):

I have just forget to add the steam to the peerConnection like this  :

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }).then((localStream) => {
      this.localVideo.nativeElement.srcObject = localStream;
      console.log('Local stream created', localStream);
      localStream.getTracks().forEach(track =>
        this.myPeerConnection.addTrack(track, localStream)
      );
```